# How to get html from element by id with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

I have simple list:

```
<ul id="tabs_nav">
    <li id="t_00">data</li>
    <li id="t_01">data</li>
    <li id="t_02">data</li>
    <li id="t_03">data</li>
</ul>
```

Now: How do I get the html of the first element, depending on what is ID. I would add that all of ID's change dynamically with the click of the button. This is my code:

```
btn.on('click',function(){
    var ladder_nav_tabs = $('#tabs_nav'),
        first_ladder_element_inset_id = ladder_nav_tabs.find('li').first().attr('id'),
        first_ladder_element_inset_html = ladder_nav_tabs.find(first_ladder_element_inset_id).html();
    console.log(first_ladder_element_inset_html);
});
```

Thx for help.

Comment: I don't really understand your question; does your code not work?

Comment: second var with first is working, i can't get html by element id...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems you are missing the id selector `#`.

You are trying to get the html from the selector:

```
ladder_nav_tabs.find(first_ladder_element_inset_id).html();
```

This won't work as an id selector needs the `#`. Like this:

```
ladder_nav_tabs.find("#" + first_ladder_element_inset_id).html();
```

Try the following to fix your code:

```
btn.on('click',function(){
    var ladder_nav_tabs = $('#tabs_nav'),
        first_ladder_element_inset_id = ladder_nav_tabs.find('li').first().attr('id'),
        first_ladder_element_inset_html = ladder_nav_tabs.find("#" + first_ladder_element_inset_id).html();
    console.log(first_ladder_element_inset_html);
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/sHAR8/) - Updating to valid id selector syntax

---

Alternatively you could shorten your code using jQuery's [**eq**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), similar to this:

```
btn.on('click',function(){
    var theHtml = $('#tabs_nav li').eq(0).html();
    console.log(theHTML);
});
```

Comment: Even if the answer is correct. The fact that you are overlooking the obvious repeated `ladder_nav_tabs.find()` is unacceptable

Comment: @Alexander: My apologies I was trying to fix OPs existing code not trying to optimize it.

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski: In addition to fixing your existing code I also added an alternate and shorter way of selecting the first `li`, using [**eq()**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) if that would suit.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use jQuery purely as a selector engine:

```
btn.onclick = function() {
  console.log(document.getElementById('tabs_nav').children[0].innerHTML);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the jQuery `first-child` [selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/). Specifically:

```
btn.on('click',function(){
    var first_child = $('#tabs_nav li:first-child');
    var first_child_html = first_child.html();
});
```

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski, no need to go in circles. The selector will give you the element, you just need to get the HTML directly from it

Comment: Again, no need to download the HTML from the first elemetu only download html element with a particular id...

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski, it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
btn.on('click',function(){
    var ladder_nav_tabs = $('#tabs_nav'),
        first_ladder_element_inset_id = ladder_nav_tabs.find('li:first-child').attr('id'),
        first_ladder_element_inset_html = ladder_nav_tabs.find(first_ladder_element_inset_id).html();
    console.log(first_ladder_element_inset_html);
});
```

You have tou use `:first-child`

Comment: Same as the others. The fact that you are overlooking the obvious repeated `ladder_nav_tabs.find()` is unacceptable