# How to get the current state of DOM in PHP?

Tags: php, html, dom

I have a very annoying problem. I have a very dynamic website where users can create all kind of elements. For example: the start with an empty list like this.

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Then they can add list items to it. Then they can click a print button that will send the list to the server and create a pdf for them. This works when the list is **not** created dynamically. But when I try the real code with dynamic HTML element creation my PHP file does not "see" these created elements because it is looking at `index.html` on the server.

This is my code that works on static pages:

```
<?php
require('/mpdf/mpdf.php');


$html = file_get_contents("index.html");
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('css/style.css');

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom -> loadHTML('$html');
$save = $dom -> saveHTML('$dom');

$list=explode("<div id=\"list\">",$save);
$list=explode("</div>",$list[1]);


$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf -> WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);
$mpdf -> WriteHTML($list[0],2);
$mpdf->Output();

exit;
?>
```

How can I give PHP an updated version of the DOM? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you not send a text version of what they dynamically created to post to your script?

Comment: No. mPDF does not work with text versions. I can't seem to get my head around how to update the Dom. The only way around it would export it to a new window and create the pdf from there with a new URL, something like: www.mydomain.com/extractedhtml .... I think :)

Comment: But... why can't you turn it in to a DOMDocument once it's posted to your code? (Since you say it's a dynamic website, I'm assuming it's being submitted via AJAX without a page reload and all that.)

Comment: Hmm, I did not think that through I think. My website is build with AngularJS. I assumed it did not reload anyway with AngularJS, but I can be very wrong now that I think about it. It is just a link now that you can click..so you are probably right...

Comment: @Jon Nope, it does not seem to work with an $http request, I don't have to do a GET or POST request. I just run the script plus the reload did not happen anyway.

Comment: I was saying that you should do a get or post and use JavaScript to get what the user did to change the dom and send that through it as text and convert it to a DOMDocument within your php. ^^

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. So keep track of the state and parse the state to the php file. Well that is a challenge :), but I can definetly think about it. Thansk for your suggestions, I really appreciate your help

Comment: For that, I would suggest a container to hold what they can change and do something similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14593727/how-to-get-html-from-element-by-id-with-jquery) to get the the content to send? :) and not a problem. If that link isn't formatted I blame being on mobile lol